Conditional Expectation of Normal Distribution $E(q+t_1|r)$
I have difficulty deriving the follow conditional expectation:
there are N cluster of $q_{ni}+t_n$, each cluster has $k_n$ elements, $q_{ni}\sim N(q,\dfrac{1}{\zeta})$, $q\sim N(q_p,\dfrac{1}{\tau})$, $t_n\sim N(0,\dfrac{1}{\eta})$, let $r=\dfrac{\sum_{n=1}^N\sum_{i=1}^{k_n}(q_{ni}+t_n)}{\sum_{n=1}^N k_n}$, the average of all data.
I'm trying to get $E(q+t_1|r)$, but when applying the Bayes' theorem, I found that $E(r|q+t_1)=q+\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^{k_1}t_1}{\sum_{n=1}^N k_n}$, then I was stuck. Can I derive the $E(q+t_1|r)$?
